# Why does transition(.opacity) doesn't work in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui

I'm using this code trying to animate the appearance of view inside an HStack. If I use this code, the appearance is not animated at all:

```
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Cart.currentItemFetchRequest()) var currentItem: FetchedResults<CartItem>

    var body: some View{
        HStack(spacing:10){
        ForEach(self.currentItem.first!.photos!) { photo in
                                SelectedPhotoView(photo: photo, currentItem: self.currentItem.first!, width: 80)
                                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration:0.3))
                                    .transition(.opacity)
                            }
        }
    }
```

but if I simply change the transition to .slide than the appearance is animated, but i'd like it to be a fadein/out. Why is it not working?

```
.transition(.slide)
```